# Firebase suddenly reports invalid signature

Tags: java, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

We are current hosting a Java/Spring server including firebase ID token verification on [SAP Cloud Platforms](https://cloudplatform.sap.com/index.html) (Hana Cloud). The authentication worked fine for the last few month, but suddenly stopped working yesterday, then it recovered after ~30 minutes and today it suddenly stopped working again. The error always is:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Firebase ID token has
> invalid signature. See
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for
> details on how to retrieve an ID token.

It is still working fine when i test it locally. What could cause this error in this unpredictable way? Are there request limits on the firebase-backend regarding Id token verification requests (which would still be strange, because other times it worked under heavy load just fine)?

Any ideas what might be causing this? I could not find really anything regarding this error.
Thanks!

Comment: Chances are there was a low-level issue like a network error preventing the call to fetch public key certificates. Unfortunately the error logged by Admin SDK is quite misleading. The logging issue has been addressed in the [latest snapshot](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/pull/64). If you can run some tests against that version, that should help determine the exact cause of the error.

Comment: Yeah we debugged the application while running on the Cloud Platform and also found that the GET request for the Google Public Keys throws an SSLHandshakeException. We believe that it is either a misconfigured firewall or ssl certificate. Neither which we can influence. Will add an answer once we know what was causing this. But thanks for the update on the error messages, they are indeed a little misleading in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there indeed was a server configuration problem with the root certificate. Sadly i cannot give any specifics, because i don't have direct access to the server and only the information the system admin gave me.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for sharing as much as you could @puelo.